# Automator - How to know what I can do with Automator in each app

Tags: applescript, automator, spotify

I'm new to AppleScript and Automator, I've reached to stop and play next and previous track in Spotify, here's what I use inside the AppleScript:

```
tell application "Spotify" to playpause
```

for play/pause^.

```
tell application "Spotify" to next track
tell application "Spotify" to previous track
```

for next and previous track^.

My question is, how can I know what else I can do with Spotify (or any other app) and automator, what any other word can I write instead "playpause", "next track" and "previous track". Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Automator and AppleScript are two very different things.

- For Automator actions for a specific app, search for the name of the app in the Actions search bar.

  [image]
- For AppleScript, open the Script Editor, then open the dictionary of the app by pressing ⇧⌘O and selecting the app. Apps not in the list probably don't have an AppleScript dictionary.

  [image]